# Error: "Unable to find the DLL xyz.dll!" Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll

I´m trying to debug my project in C++ Visual Studio 2010. When I click the debug-button an error appears with: Error:

> Unable to find the DLL xyz.dll

I put the `xyz.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32\*`. I can start the .exe of the project, when the xyz.dll is in the same path. So how can I debug my project so that the `xyz.dll` is recognized?

Comment: Copy it into the build directory, the one where your EXE is getting built.  Unclear if this is a C# or C++ question, in C++ you use xcopy in a post-build event.

Comment: It´s a C++ question. So whats that xcopy with post-build event? I rly don´t know yet how to handle with VS2010 with C++.

Comment: As Hans said, copy the DLL "into the build directory, the one where your EXE is getting built". If you don't want to do it with xcopy in a post-build event, fine, then do it your way.

Comment: Don't copy your DLLs in the `C:\Windows\System32\` directory. It's how things were done 20 years ago and it will only lead to tears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was an embrassing fault by myself. The Debugger was set on Win32 as default and I was using a x64 dll. So I changed the Debugger to x64 and it worked!
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

It must be in the same directory as the .exe, or you can modify your path variable to the location of that dll, but modifying the path variable is not recommended for something like this.